# CheckBox in GridView firing CheckedChanged event at wrong time

Tags: asp.net, gridview, event-handling

I have a checkbox in my gridview footer with autopostack=true (which should fire a checkedchanged event), and a linkbutton in my itemtemplate (which should fire the gridview rowcommand event).

Everything has been working fine, until I placed the following code in my gridview rowdatabound (or databound) event:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gridCartRows.Columns.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = gridCartRows.Columns.Count - 1;
```

Now, when I click my linkbutton, the checkbox checkedchanged event is automatically fired, and then the rowcommand event is fired.

Why is the checkedchanged event being fired when it shouldn't, when I add the above code?

Is there a way to get around this?

**Edit**

Here's a sample, that reproduces my issue:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="True"
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Fire Row Command" CommandName="Fire" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    Footer
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = new int[5];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = GridView1.Columns.Count - 1;

        ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked = true;
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Fire")
    {
        Response.Write("RowCommand fired.");
    }
}

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("CheckBox fired.");
}
```

Note, I'm setting the CheckBox property to true in the RowDataBound - if I remove this, it works fine. So merging the cells and setting the checkbox property aren't working nicely together.

Comment: You are messing up viewstate. Instead of removing row in this way, consider removing from datasource and rebinding the gridview.

Comment: @afzalulh This is a *footer* row. I'm trying to merge the footer cells...

Comment: Did you check if the row is footer like `if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)`?

Comment: @afzalulh Yes, and that part is working - my cells are being merged as expected. My issue is that the checkbox is firing its checkedchanged event at the wrong time. (Please read OP...)

Comment: Are you creating your grid dynamically? If not, can you please post markup for the GridView?

Comment: No, I'm not creating my grid dynamically. I posted code to reproduce. I realized if I don't set the CheckBox checked property it also works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView Control events are stored in viewstate and they can get messed up very easily. Here removing a cell causing to bind different event to link button. Although after postback  __EVENTTARGET is LinkButton, wrong method is called and wrong control, event arguments are passed.

I would suggest to hide the cell rather than removing it:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].ColumnSpan = GridView1.Columns.Count - 1;
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

        ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked = true;
    }
}
```

This will serve the purpose.